# How to determine if the changes happened via the API or by human?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to determine if the changes to a file happened via the API or via a human through the spreadsheet webapp?

Comment: no there isn't.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is difference between `the API` and `a human through the spreadsheet webapp`? 2. Is `the API` Sheets API? 3. What is "the spreadsheet webapp"? 4. Does "the spreadsheet webapp" edit the Spreadsheet using Sheets API?